# Trying to retrieve an avatar image from an API but receiving an error of avatar not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**userData** is a function that receives user data from an API using **getUserByChainAccount**. **getUserByChainAccount** requires a username, which in this case is dynamically retrieved from **buyer**.

I'm interested in **avatar** , but I keep getting the following error **Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: avatar is not defined**

```
function UserTransactionsComponent() {
  const [sales, setSales] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales'
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setSales(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!sales) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <ul>
        {sales.map((result) => {
          const {
            sale_id,
            buyer,
            seller,
            listing_price,
            listing_symbol,
            created_at_time,
          } = result;
          const userData = async (buyer) => {
            const user = await proton.getUserByChainAccount(buyer);
            const { name, avatar } = user;
          };

          function HandleBuyerClick() {
            window.location = '/user/' + buyer;
          }
          function HandleSellerClick() {
            window.location = '/user/' + seller;
          }

          if (buyer !== null) {
            return (
              <Card>
                <li key={sale_id}>
                  <h3>
                    <Transaction>
                      {avatar}
                      <Button onClick={HandleSellerClick}>{seller}</Button>
                    </Transaction>{' '}
                    just sold item number
                    <Transaction>
                      <Button>{sale_id}</Button>
                    </Transaction>{' '}
                    to{' '}
                    <Transaction>
                      <Button onClick={HandleBuyerClick}>{buyer}</Button>
                    </Transaction>{' '}
                    for <Transaction>{formatNumber(listing_price)}</Transaction>{' '}
                    {listing_symbol} at {parseTimestampJM(created_at_time)}
                  </h3>
                </li>
              </Card>
            );
          }
        })}
      </ul>
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default UserTransactionsComponent;
```

Comment: Which line did the error say it was on?

Answer (score 1):

Making an API request *during rendering* is a famously bad idea.  React might re-render for a variety of reasons, such as this component or any parent component updating its state.  It would be silly to re-request the same API results over and over and over on every render.  Not to mention that trying to shoehorn *asynchronous* operations into a render operation is going to be difficult and buggy.

Requests like that should be made when the component is loaded and the results should be stored in state.

In this case your best bet is probably to make an entirely separate component to render within the `.map()` operation, and pass that component what it needs to make the API request.  For example, consider a `.map()` like this:

```
{sales.map((result) => {
  return <SomeOtherComponent result={result} />
})}
```

Then within *that* component you would handle your API call and manage the state of the result of that call.  For example, within `SomeOtherComponent` you might do this:

```
const {
  sale_id,
  buyer,
  seller,
  listing_price,
  listing_symbol,
  created_at_time,
} = props.result;

const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(''); // <-- define the state here

useEffect(() => {
  const userData = async (buyer) => {
    const user = await proton.getUserByChainAccount(buyer);
    const { name, avatar } = user;
    setAvatar(avatar); // <--- update the state here
  };
  userData();
}, []);

// define your click handlers as you already do here

// return your JSX markup as you already do here
```

Comment: Great answer. Your response left me with a few questions. I edited my original code to show you its entirety. You'll notice that I have a total of 2 API requests here. As you mentioned, one of the requests happens inside the render operation, this one is supposed to bring in the **avatar** data.

The other API uses state, similar to what you describe, but the data is mapped within the render operation. 

I've tried to have the data for both functions (**userData** and **UserTransactionsComponent**) mapped above the rendering operation but I can't get them to work (result is undefined)

Comment: @Mooch: That looks like a separate problem.  But if `result` (in the `.map()` callback) is `undefined` then that suggests that `sales` isn't what you expect it to be.  You'll want to debug to find out what it is.  You can `console.log` the `sales` value just before the component returns its rendered result and see what that value contains.  But, again, this sounds like a separate issue and worth isolating into its own [mcve] for a new question.